# Laravel x Hostinger SCSS not loading when deployed

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, laravel-mix

I've been developing a web app in Laravel. I've recently wanted to deploy a preview in the production server so I uploaded the files to the hostinger but the scss did not load nor the routing to my controllers. I didn't really find much info on the topic since I don't really know what to look for, I believe it may be my htaccess file but idk id that even makes sense:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I ran NPM run production and Im working with mix, my package.json is configured like this:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "commonjs",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "hot": "mix hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.63.6",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
        "jquery": "^3.7.0",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "webpack": "^5.88.1"
    }
}
```

My webApp works perfectly on localhost, but then again on prod my scss styles dont load nor does it fin my controllers. Im calling the html tag for scss in a layout head tag like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: "_the html tag for scss_" That's for CSS, browsers can't interpret SCSS

Comment: what final URL is generated when you use `mix('css/app.css')`? If you try adding `public` after your domain, for example: `domain.com/public/css/app.css`, does it work? if the answer is yes, then you have something wrong, I know hostinger does not use `public` nor allows you to change the root folder. I would suggest changing to another host, maybe use AWS EC2 Free Tier

Comment: You're rewriting _everything_ through `public/index.php` - that does not work for CSS, JS, images or other static files.

Comment: @matiaslauriti `mix('css/app.css')` returns `/css/app.css`, when domain is added manually it does load the css properly. Thank you for the advise but my client is not willing to pay other host since he has some other projects in the current host.

Comment: @brombeer so do I have to be less specific in my htaccess file for the js, css, etc to load?

Comment: I think there are howtos available on how to install laravel on hostinger. iirc, hostinger uses a `public_html` folder - putting all of Laravel's files into this folder is _not_ recommended, there are files in Laravel that should never be publicly accessible

Comment: @JuanPabloArangoLizcano as brombeer said, hostinger is not a good host for this, it should be a host that allows you to ONLY expose the `public` folder, everything else is open to being accessed from outside and is a very high-security risk. Unless you find a super good tutorial or you are very knowledgeable with Apache (`.htaccess` policies), you could potentially leave something publicly accessible, and that is not good at all. Usually hosts that give you a virtual machine for you to handle is the way to go with these types of projects, but I understand you do have a very tough client...

Comment: Instructions on how to use `public_html`: https://gist.github.com/johanvanhelden/29096a9ff31eac9b039d36056919abbb#file-reconfigure-laravel-instructions-md

Comment: @matiaslauriti: As I understand things, Hostinger has several hosting options available, including "shared hosting" which is what the OP seems to be describing. The public_html is, I believe, publicly visible, but subfolders of this folder are not visible unless you, the creator using this host, makes it so. So, a Laravel application would generally go into a subdomain, one located within a sub-folder off of the public_html folder, and thus would not be visible or accessible by the public.

Comment: @matiaslauriti: (continued) All public files of the Laravel application, including the index.php file, would be in sub-folder of this folder, named "public", and this would also be publicly available. It would then be easy to tell Hostinger to start your website from this public sub-sub-folder, and I think that security would be reasonably maintained (it is impossible to have absolute security). This is no different from security concerns that are encountered with other shared hosting services.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels in that case you are right. My experience with hostings that only have `public_html` is that you cannot place anything before it, and if you can, PHP is not allowed to open/view the parent folder, but maybe hostinger allows you to

Comment: @matiaslauriti with shared hosting, you the site creator only have access to public_html and any sub-folders that you may create. There are exceptions of course, depending on the exact product you purchase.

Comment: @matiaslauriti: I am no expert on this subject, but rather have paid for a shared hosting site on Hostinger. It's cheaper than dedicated hosting but with limited options. In retrospect, I have to wonder if I'd have been better off using cloud hosting, but that's for a future decision, when this current site contract expires.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree with you, still you can get a good machine for $5 on AWS EC2 or DigitalOcean, but depends a lot on the traffic and what the project/system is doing

Comment: thank you guys, I was able to solve fixing the mix manifest but I appreciate the comments on the public access. I agree it shouldn`t be done if possible but my client wants it in Hostinger anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by editing my `public/mix-manifest.json` changing the paths to a relative route:
from this

```
{
"/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"}
```

to this:

```
{
"/js/app.js": "./js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "./css/app.css"}
```

and my htaccess  generated with looking like this:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```